# Create react route get request for mongodb data using a key and value and not just id

Tags: mongodb, react-native, react-router

I currently have code that creates a route such as localhost:5000/services/5e2e98d0f3b0156f5caed9a9 to get data in mongodb given a certain id. What I am trying to figure out is that is there a way to create a route such as following, localhost:5000/services/parking, to get all data which has a service of parking?

```
//Current code to get info by id
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  Service.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(service => res.json(service))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

//Example data on how currently a data is stored in mongodb 
{
    "location": {
        "coordinates": [
            -121.880731,
            37.339349
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "_id": "5e2e98d0f3b0156f5caed9a9",
    "service": "parking",
    "building": "North Parking Garage",
    "description": "6-story parking structure located on the corner of S. 10th and E.  San Fernando Streets",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-27T08:01:20.164Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-27T08:01:20.164Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: you want to create one page which shows your all services .Am i Right ???

Comment: There are different services such as parking, dining, and printers in one mongodb collection. Is there a way to create a route to do a GET request to get information for one type of service such as parking only? I am currently trying to test the backend using POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using the find() and pass in key and the request param id which is the value passed in the URI

```
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  Service.find({"service": req.params.id})
    .then(service => res.json(service))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```